# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_121" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 50)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm building an LSTM model for time series data, but I got this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_121" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 50)
```

My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(LSTM(50, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(LSTM(50, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

The dimension of the `X_train` is `(1198, 60, 1)` and the one of `y_train` is `(1198,)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the LSTM layer expects a 3D input, while your 3rd and 4th LSTM layers are receiving a 2D input of shape `(None, 50)` since `return_sequences` is set to `False` (the default) in the 2nd and 3rd LSTM layers, while it should be set to `True`.

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

X_train = np.random.normal(size=(1198, 60, 1))
y_train = np.mean(X_train, axis=1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(LSTM(50, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128)
```